# Ruby Regular Expression: Find the last punctuation

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to find the last punctuation or space character in a sentence.

Given I have the sentence, `"Hello! What is your name?"`

I want the regular expression to return the index of the `?`, but my regex is returning the index of the `!`

My attempt:

```
> s = "Hello! What is your name?"
> s =~ /([[:punct:]\s])/
> puts $+
!
=> nil
```

I believe `$+` returns the highest match, so the last match, but it's only matching the first.

Thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The match against

```
/[[:punct:]\s][^[:punct]\s]*\z/
```

results in 24 for your example.

The regexp matches a punctuation or space followed by only non-punctuation-or-space characters and then the string end. So, it will find the last punctuation/space in the string.

`$+` does not help because it does not magically match the regexp several times. It just returns the last group of the most recent match. If you have e.g. 7 groups in your expression it will be equal to `$7`.

```
"abcdefghijklmnopq" =~ /(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)/  # 0
$+ # "g"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes perfect sense! I don't know why I didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 5):

To find the last match use `rindex`:

```
s = "Hello! What is your name?"
i = s.rindex(/[[:punct:]]/)
puts i
```

Result:

```
24
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/n0UPL)

Comment: Thank you for informing me of the typo, I didn't copy/paste, I re-typed it.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I had no idea of rindex either. Sounds like we have two solutions. Thanks!!